# Replace the pipe character "|" with line breaks?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to use Regex in my Ruby program to convert "|" character into a line breaker, so for example:

```
# convert("title|subtitle") => "title \n subtitle"
```

The regex I'm trying is the following:

```
title_params =~ s/\|/\\n/
```

But I kept getting errors saying that "|" is not recognized.

Comment: In Ruby you do not use the `sed` style `s/foo/bar/` to replace text, you use the [`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regex is not needed for this simple problem:

```
=> puts "foo|bar".tr("|","\n")
foo
bar
```

Comment: See the [`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr) method for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know the syntax of your way of doing this but this works fine for me.

```
>> a = "title | subtitle"
=> "title | subtitle"
>> a.gsub(/\|/,"\n")
=> "title \n subtitle"
```

Comment: Or even `a.gsub( "|", "\n" )`